# Redis users getting deleted automatically

Tags: redis

i have a redis instance which is installed as a linux service. 
I have created few users with some RBAC policies. 
Everything works fine as expected for few days, but suddenly all my newly created users get deleted due to which my application connecting to redis is throwing exception.
Also, no other person can access this server except me.

Can someone help me how to persist the newly created users in redis for lifetime?

Answer (score 1):

> Everything works fine as expected for few days, but suddenly all my newly created users get deleted

After ruling out other trivial reasons (connecting to the wrong instance, for example), I believe your Redis service was simply restarted for some reason, perhaps after a server restart.

Once an ACL rule is created/modified/updated, the configuration needs to **persisted** to a file to make it survive a Redis restart; to do that, run either:

- `CONFIG REWRITE`, if you are specifying your ACL users / rules inside your main configuration file (the default option);
- `ACL SAVE`, if you are using an external ACL file.

To learn more about how Redis deals with ACLs, be sure to check out the [official documentation](https://redis.io/docs/management/security/acl/).